# Can you show this is a bilinear form?

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, bilinear-form

I'm reading Scharlau's Quadratic and Hermitian forms.
In it he defines a quadratic form as

"Let V be a vector space over a field K. A map $q:V\mapsto K$ is called a quadratic form on $V$ if $$q(\alpha x)=\alpha^2q(x)$$ for all $x\in V,\alpha \in K$ and $b_q(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}(q(x+y)-q(x)-q(y))$ is a (necessarily symmetric) bilinear form".

However I'm having trouble verifying it's a bilinear form.Here is my attempt.\

$$b(x+x',y)=\frac{1}{2}((q(x+x'+y)-q(x+x')-q(y))$$
here I get stuck as I don't see how I can get this to split any further so I get $b(x+x',y)=b(x,y)+b(x',y)$

I'm also stuck on the scalar multiplication property of bilinear forms. Here is my attempt. $$b(\alpha x,y)=\frac{1}{2}(q(\alpha x+y)-q(\alpha x)-q(y)= \frac{1}{2}(q(\alpha x+y)-\alpha ^2q(x)-q(y))$$ again I don't see how I can split this any further to show $b(\alpha x,y)=\alpha b(x,y)$

Can anyone give me an idea how to progress into showing this is a bilinear form?

Comment: I don't understand why anybody would downvote this question. It is clearly an earnest attempt to use the site exactly as the site claims it is intended to be used. (+1, btw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what's going on.

Per the comments under Jose Carlos Santos' answer, in order to be called a quadratic form, the function $q:V\rightarrow K$ must satisfy 2 distinct requirements:

(1) $q(\alpha x) = \alpha^2 q(x)$ for all $\alpha\in K, x\in V$.

(2) The function $b_q:V\times V\rightarrow K$ defined by the equation $b_q(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}(q(x+y) - q(x) - q(y))$ must be a bilinear function.

The second requirement is part of the definition of being called a quadratic form. If $q$ satisfies (1) but not (2), it is not a quadratic form.

So what's going on is just that you were mildly misreading Scharlau's definition. (I was too, at first.)

To see that it is possible to satisfy (1) without satisfying (2), observe that (1) only exerts any control over how $q$ behaves when you scale its input with a scalar factor. It doesn't exert any control on how $q$'s values on a pair of linearly independent vectors are related. (Whereas the bilinearity of $b_q$ clearly requires some sort of relationship of this kind.)

Exploiting this idea to build a concrete example:

Let $V=\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $K=\mathbb{R}$. Construct a candidate $q$ as follows: take an absolutely arbitrary function $g$ on the half-open interval $[0,\pi)$. Now every line through the origin goes through exactly one of the points $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ for $\theta \in [0,\pi)$. This implies that for any nonzero $v\in \mathbb{R}^2$, there is a unique $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ and a unique $\theta\in [0,\pi)$ such that $v = (\beta\cos\theta,\beta\sin\theta)$. Now define $q(v)$ by the formula $q(v) := \beta^2 g(\theta)$. (And define $q(0)= 0$.)

I claim that the $q$ so defined satisfies $q(\alpha v) = \alpha^2 q(v)$ for any $v\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and any $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$. Indeed, if $v = (\beta\cos\theta, \beta\sin\theta)$ for some $\beta\in\mathbb{R},\theta\in[0,\pi)$, then for any $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ we have

$$q(\alpha v) = q(\alpha\beta\cos\theta,\alpha\beta\sin\theta) = (\alpha\beta)^2 g(\theta) = \alpha^2(\beta^2g(\theta)) =\alpha^2 q(v).$$

Since the original function $g$ was completely arbitrary, $q$ is potentially a mess. (For example, we could let $g$ be some form of the Dirichlet function - $1$ when $\theta$ is a rational fraction of $\pi$, $0$ when it's an irrational fraction of $\pi$.) Then $b_q$ can't hope to be bilinear.

Comment: Ok thanks, I didnt realise this was necessarily part of the definition. Most sources just state (1) or that it is a homogenous polynomial of degree 2. Thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: Adding an example to show it is possible to satisfy (1) without satisfying (2) (or being a homogeneous polynomial of degree 2).

Comment: "Being a homogeneous poly. of deg 2" is also a correct definition and is equivalent to Scharlau's (as long as the field characteristic is not 2). The advantage of Scharlau's definition is that it is not married to any specific set of coordinates on $V$, whereas to define a polynomial we need coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't seem to make sense. Of course that you cannot verify *in general* that $b_q$ is bilinear. That can only be done for a *concrete* function $q$. If you provide a concrete example of a potential quadratic form $q$ then, yes, we can help you to check whether or not $b_q$ is bilinear.

Comment: I was under the impression that it is a general theorem in this situation that if $q$ is a quadratic form, $b_q$ is bilinear.

Comment: @BenBlum-Smith It is *not* a theorem The OP stated that it is a definition.

Comment: I see. That $b_q$ is bilinear is a requirement of calling $q$ quadratic.

Comment: So using the properties of quadratic forms it is not possible to show that this is in fact a bilinear forrm? there is no concrete function q given. If I assume $b_q$ is a bilinear form can I show $q$ is a quadratic form for general $b_q$ and $q$?

Comment: @user24907 - you will be able to show that as long as the characteristic of $K$ is not 2 so that the definition of $b_q$ makes sense.

Comment: @user24907 Sure. The function $q$ is a quadratic form if and only if $q(\alpha x)=\alpha^2 q(x)$ and $b_q$ is bilinear.

Comment: but if it is an if and only if statement the shouldnt I be able to show that if $q$ is a quadratic form then $q(\alpha x)=\alpha ^2 q(x)$ and $b_q$ is bilinear?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos - It's clear the OP asked the question under the same misimpression I was under. Perhaps it would improve the answer to explicitly address this misimpression in the answer?

Comment: @user24907 Evey definition is actualy a “if and only if” statement. Like: $n$ is even if and only if $2\mid n$. Often, the “and only if” part is omitted, but it's as if it was there.

Comment: Ok so then I dont understand why assuming q is quadratic doesnt allow me to show $b_q$ is bilinear ?

Comment: @user24907 Of course you can use it to show that $b_q$ is bilinear, but it is tautological, because that's part of what being bilinear means.

Comment: But I cant do it for general $q_b$ and $q$?

Comment: @user24907 *How* do you want to do it in general? What does that even *mean*?

Comment: Assume $q(x)$ is quadraric and show $b_q (x,y)=\frac{1}{2}(q(x+y)-q(x)-q(y))$ is bilinear that is linear in each argument ?

Comment: @user24907 If $q$ is quadratic then, by the definition of quadratic form, $b_q$ is bilinear.

Comment: I see the isssue. By assuming $q$ is quadratic I'm also assuming $b_q$ is bilinear. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @user24907 I'm glad I could help, but please note that I had already said that in my second comment.